# Combine [numberpad] and [numpad]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

[numpad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/numpad): 17 questions asked, with a wiki

> A numpad or numeric keypad is the small, palm-sized, seventeen key section of a computer keyboard.

[numberpad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/numberpad): 31 questions asked, no wiki

Based on the questions asked for these two tags, they seem to mean the exact same thing. I propose that we combine the tags, as well as update the wiki. Quite a few of the tagged questions involve the numberpad keyboard on mobile devices, so the wiki ought to reflect that.